# Laravel : use lazy with offset and limit does not seem to work

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to split some processing on my models process in several jobs.
Let's say I have 300 models I want to process.
I want to launch 3 jobs, each job will handle 100 models.
In each job, I want to lazy load by group of 10 models.

If I execute the following code :

```
$models = MyModel::offset(0)->limit(100)->lazy(10);
$j = 0;

foreach ($models as $model) {
  $j++;
}
echo $j;
```

The output is :
`300`
Where I thought only 100 models should be processed.

I don't understand why all my models are processed.

If someone knows the truth ... :)

Answer (score 7):

Well, it seems I got lost, this works:

```
MyModel::lazy(10)->skip(0)->take(100);
```